# Как в динамическую таблицу DBGridEh вставить поле CHECKBOX

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Подскажите, как в динамическую таблицу DBGridEh вставить поле CHECKBOX. Используется база данных FIREBIRD. Поле в FIREBIRD для CHECKBOX изменяется -1 или 0 что означает  -1 - True; 0 - False.
  Привожу пример

```
procedure TZakaz_Form.mySerch;
```

-тут формируется SQL запрос

```
procedure TZAKAZ_FORM.Set_Main_Form_Spisok_Fields(Vid_Type: Integer); 
Columns.Clear;
Set_Razmer (0, 'POS_BELEG_ID', 0, 0, 0, 'ID');
```

и т.д. - Тут я описываю название столбцов задаю размер и сразу вставляю значения.

```
 procedure TZAKAZ_FORM.Set_Razmer(Field_Number: Integer; Field_Name: String; Field_Width, Field_Alignment, Field_Title_Alignment: Integer; Field_Title_Caption: String);
begin
    with suiDBGrid do
    begin
        Columns.Add;
        Columns[Field_Number].FieldName := Field_Name;
        Columns[Field_Number].Width     := Field_Width;
```

и т.д

Answer (score 1):

Из документации:
"Grid автоматически отображает checkbox'ы для boolean-полей. Для отображения checkbox'ов для не-boolean полей заполните первую строку свойства Column.KeyList, которая соответствует значению 'checked' checkbox'а, вторая строка - значению 'non checked' и установите свойство Column.Checkboxes в True. Cтрока в KeyList может содержать более одного значения, разделенных точкой с запятой."

перевод mmlm.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но данный способ работает только для фиксированных полей таблицы,а у меня меняется она в соответствии и поле CHECKBOX смещается. 
  Поэтому я и спрашиваю, может кто то решал такую задачу.

Comment: В соответствии с чем?

Comment: @kadekin778 В чем проблема сделать все тоже самое программно в рантайме перед заполнением таблицы?